# Salvar tempo que usuário assistiu vídeo e continuar assistindo

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Bom, acabei um curso de PHP, não sou expert e estou criando um sistema de curso. Preciso que quando o usuário começar a assistir a aula, o sistema salve o tempo de execução do vídeo de 3 em 3 segundos. E salve isso para que da próxima vez que ele entre no site, ele possa continuar de onde parou! Pensei em fazer com localStorage, cookies e outros. Mas eu preciso que de onde o usuário acessar, ele possa continuar assistindo. Pensei em enviar o tempo para o Banco de Dados. Só não sei qual estrutura e função fazer isso. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

> Eu recomendo que uses Ajax

Aqui tens uma funcao para enviar dados para o servidor sem atualizar a pagina.

```
function SendDataToServer(_data)
{
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          // Aqui podes ignorar se nao quiseres receber nada do servidor
          console.log("Texto recebido do servidor -> " + this.responseText);
      }
  };
  // Aqui envia os dados 
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/TeuFicheiro.php?data="+_data, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Podes chamar assim

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    SendDataToServer("Utilizador X assistiu X segundos");
}, 3000);
```

> setInterval(funcao, tempo) chama a funcao a cada 3 segundos